# Construct a sequence of automated actions in Alfresco Content Services community edition

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I would like your help with a setup of actions that I wish to construct on ACS, but after reading the documentation and other articles/posts/etc I am really confused about how/if it can be done.

I am using Alfresco Content Services Community Edition: version 7.4.0-M3, that I deployed using the official "community-docker-compose.yml" file from [here](https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-deployment/blob/master/docker-compose/community-docker-compose.yml)

I have created several Groups, Users, a Site and different Folders per User in this Site.
Now I wish to construct a sequence of automated actions. I will provide an example below:

> Every time "User A" uploads a file in "folder A", this file should be forwarded and assigned for review to "User B".
> "User B" will review the file and if everything is okay, he will forward the file to "User C".
> But if "User B" finds some issues in the file, he must sent it back to "User A" with some comments.
> "User A" will fix the file based on these comments, re-upload it, and the sequence of tasks should automatically begin again from scratch until the file finally reaches "User C".

> After the file reaches "User C", other sequences of automated actions should take place, that will more-or-less follow the same logic as the previous one.
> These sequences should automatically start for each new file that is being uploaded.

After a few tries, I realized that this cannot be achieved with the Workflows that ACS comes installed with by-default. I understand that a new workflow definition needs to be constructed.
Please correct me if I am wrong or if I am missing something so far.

- Can you please name a few ways in order to achieve this?
- I read that I can design these actions using the enterprise product "Alfresco Digital Workspace". Is this correct?
- Shoud I design my workflows using Eclipse+Activiti and then upload them to my ACS instance? Is this possible?

Ideally, what I need is a way to make these automated sequences of action work using Community Edition not Enterprise, if possible.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Try look at this tutorial https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html. It will help you to understand how to create and deploy workflow into community edition. If you use java liseners on tasks you can simple make logic for moving document based on exact users. To start workflow you can use let users to do it manually (same as now for default workflows). Or you can make simple action or behavior to start it. But it depends if user A have to each time set who is users B and C then user A have to fill form where to specified all users.

Comment: Thanks @DavidDejmal I'll have a look.